# Registering a JSONm store in sencha touch

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs, sencha-touch-2, sencha-touch-theming

I am new in sencha touch application development .I am trying to load some data from remote we server to a list . I created a Store like the following

```
Ext.regStore('customers',{

model : 'customer',
sorters : 'firstName',
storeId : 'customers',
data : [{
    id : 100,
    firstName : 'aaa'
}, {
    id : 101,
    firstName : 'sss'
}, {
    id : 102,
    firstName : 'rrrr'
}]
```

});

Now I need to modify this store to retrieve data from external server.Follwoing is the code i am using right now

```
var customers = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
        model : 'customer',

           proxy : {
            type : 'ajax',
            url:'http:sample.com',

            reader : {
                type : 'json',
                root : '',
            },                              
        },

        listeners : {

            datachanged : function() {

                customers.each(function(r) {
                    console.log('data in record is:'+ r.get('name'));
                });
            }
        },
    });
```

Now my doubt is that how to register this JSON store like the inital code to access the store from another viewcontroller file.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the property:

**storeId = "NameOfStoryID"**

After filling your store you can, later on in your code, use this storeId to access the store (get the data, update it etc).

Example:

```
    var schouwLijstStore = new Ext.data.Store({

        model: "schouwLijst",
        storeId: "myStore",
        proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            url: 'php/json.php?t=list',
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                root: 'list'
            },   
        },    
        autoLoad: true,
        listeners: {
            load: function() {

                               // Do things on load (sync to offline store for example)

            }

        }

    });
```

Now to access your store later on in the code you can use your storeID. For example to load it:

// Load
myStore.load();

// Add item
myStore.add({ id: **, value: ** });

etc.